# avoid use of a global variable

Tags: function-construction

I am writing some piece of code to do some numerical integration by hand. To this end, I discretize the interval [0,1] on a grid $x_0=0,x_1,\dots,x_{Nmax-1},x_{Nmax}=1$ and compute the value of the integral on elementary intervals $[x_{n-1},x_{n}]$, I call the resulting function `B[n]`. (My actual situation is more complicated because actually each integral also depends on another point of the grid so I really have `B[n,m]`). My problem is that for the extremal values $x_0,x_1,x_{Nmax-1},x_Nmax$ the function is different and I need to set this by hand.
For instance

```
B[n_]=Log[x[n]-x[n-1]];
B[1]=Log[x[1]]/2;
B[Nmax-1]=Log[x[Nmax-1]-1]/2+1;
B[Nmax]=0;
```

This is really a sort of baby example but my problem here is what to do with the quantity Nmax. In some cases I have to use things like `B[n/;n>=1&&n<=Nmax-1]` but that's a real pain to know if subsequent definitions of this function `B` will clash with this, or if they require that Nmax was given a value before being evaluated, etc. In the final version of the code, the grid would be defined before evaluating all those definitions, but I can't help but thinking that there must be a cleaner way to do this. So far, I have been doing a mixture of playing with `=` versus `:=` and also calling function `BNmaxminusone` and this sort of things, but that's really ugly.

Comment: I would use "Which": Nmax = 10;
B[n_] := Which[n < 1, 0, n == 1, Log[x[1]]/2, n < Nmax - 1, 
  Log[x[n] - x[n - 1]], n == Nmax - 1, Log[x[Nmax - 1] - 1]/2 + 1, 
  True, 0]

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want a global variable `Nmax`, you can use `With` to bake the value into `B`:

```
With[{Nmax = 10},
  B[n_]=Log[x[n]-x[n-1]];
  B[1]=Log[x[1]]/2;
  B[Nmax-1]=Log[x[Nmax-1]-1]/2+1;
  B[Nmax]=0;
]
```

You can look at the `DownValues` or `Definition` of `B` to check that `Nmax` has disappeared and been replaced with 10 in all definitions of `B`.